# Tomcat Servlet 3.0 multipart file upload name clash in temp folder

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, file-upload, multipart

It appears Tomcat is not handling parallel uploads of the same multipart file by two different users.

**Test**

- Two sessions/users A & B
- Both upload a 20MB file *with the same name* `foo.pdf` more or less at the same time
- Servlet 3.0 Request with default configuration stores the two files in the tmp folder
- Both threads try to write that `foo.pdf` into the tmp folder

**Result**

- The uploaded document is corrupt (two streams writing to it)
- The slower request will fail with a `FileNotFoundException` as the tmp file was already deleted by the cleanup task of the faster request.

Is there a way to avoid this - other than setting `fileSizeThreshold` higher than `maxFileSize` so it would never be written to disk in the first place.

Side note: this is a Spring Boot 2.1 application but this is irrelevant as it uses this Servlet 3.0 implementation by default.

Comment: That is strange because normally if you create a temp file it's name would be something like *foo4516312942348137264.pdf*. Is it ok if A uploads **fooA.pdf** and B uploads **fooB.pdf**? Can you show how you do the processing of `MultipartFile`?

Comment: The name of the temp file may be random (I didn't check) but it's obviously the same for both requests.

Comment: Apache commons-fileupload obviously doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer but it's not really satisfactory. We didn't figure out how to make this work with Tomcat's Servlet 3.0 implementation. However, once we switched to Apache commons-fileupload all was well.

So, for [Spring (Boot) applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-multipart) you would

- set `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled: false`
- configure a bean of type `CommonsMultipartResolver` with a name of `multipartResolver`
- add the `commons-fileupload` dependency